# How do I set up my API service on Uffizzi?

Tags: deployment, hosting

If I can get set up on Uffizzi cloud, is it just as simple as starting and deploying my app to allow others to use my API or do I have to give some kind of special privileges through Uffizzi or add additional features to my application?

Comment: You've posted 6 very vague questions about different aspects of the same thing. Stack Overflow is a service to help developers find problems, but we're not here to save you from doing basic research yourself. You would be better off deleting all of the questions, doing some more research, and then if you hit **specific** problems, come back to Stack Overflow with questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can run your API service on Uffizzi

You need to package it in a Docker container (code + Docker file into Docker Image https://docs.docker.com/) and upload it to Dockerhub.  You can make it public or private.

After you set up your uffizzi cloud account you can connect your dockerhub account and import the image directly into your cloud environment (multiple options here explained in the UI).

Make sure you know how your API service will network externally and what port it listens on - you'll have to input that into the Uffizzi UI

If your API service or requires a supporting app you can run both containers in the same environment and they can talk to one another on local host.